# JS Reduce first item in returned array is null

Tags: javascript, angular

Hi I am using the following function to group by a key and calculate a total:

```
calcEquipmentTotals(){
    var groups = this.inspection.equipments.reduce(function(obj,item){
      obj[item.equipment_type_id] = obj[item.equipment_type_id] || { equipment_type_id: item.equipment_type_id, total: 0};
      // Calculate total based on action
      var total = obj[item.equipment_type_id].total;
      if(item.action === 'added' || item.action === 'stocktake'){
        total = total + item.quantity;
      }else{
        total = total - item.quantity;
      };
      obj[item.equipment_type_id].total = total;
      return obj;
    },[]);
    return groups;
  }
```

This is working great except the first item is an empty object, what am I doing wrong here?

```
[ null, { "equipment_type_id": 1, "total": 1 }, { "equipment_type_id": "2", "total": 10 } ]
```

Comment: Probably there is no item that has an`equipment_type_id` of 0

Comment: Why your initial value is array instead of object literal?

Comment: @HikmatGurbanli Because I get this error from Angular if I use {}:
Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Comment: well, then treat it as an array in reduce's callback. you are not pushing items, you are assigning some indexes, and some indexes will be null

Comment: Use an object to do the grouping, then once you've done the grouping transform it into an Array using `Object.keys(obj).map((key) => obj[key])`

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want.

```
 calcEquipmentTotals() {
  var groups = this.inspection.equipments.reduce(function (map, item) {

    const obj = map.get(item.equipment_type_id) || {
      equipment_type_id: item.equipment_type_id, total: 0
    };

    if (item.action === 'added' || item.action === 'stocktake') {
      obj.total += item.quantity;
    } else {
      obj.total -= item.quantity;
    };
    map.set(obj);

    return map;
  }, new Map());
  return Array.from(groups.values());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The comments pointed me in the right direction, this is what got it done in the end:

```
calcEquipmentTotals(){
    var groups = this.inspection.equipments.reduce(function(obj,item){
      obj[item.equipment_type_id] = obj[item.equipment_type_id] || { equipment_type_id: item.equipment_type_id, total: 0};
      // Calculate total based on action
      var total = obj[item.equipment_type_id].total;
      if(item.action === 'added' || item.action === 'stocktake'){
        total = total + item.quantity;
      }else{
        total = total - item.quantity;
      };
      obj[item.equipment_type_id].total = total;
      return obj;
    },{});
    return Object.keys(groups).map((key) => groups[key]);
  }
```